# How to find correct result using C# binary search? (&print the process)

Tags: c#, backend, binary-search-tree

I want to find an correct result by using C# binary search

here's my code

```
using System;

namespace BinarySearch
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int BinarySearch(int[] Numbers,int SearchItems)
        {
            int start = 0;
            int end = Numbers.Length - 1;
            while (start<=end)
            {
                int mid = (start + end) / 2;
                if (SearchItems<Numbers[mid])
                {
                    end = mid - 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    start = mid + 1;
                }
            }
            return -1;

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Provide input search No. :");
            int SearchItems = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] Numbers = { 8, 44, 26, 67, 35, 12, 77, 75, 31, 2, 62, 4, 88, 17 };
            int result = BinarySearch(Numbers, SearchItems);
            if (result<0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{SearchItems} is not found!");

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{SearchItems} is found at index:{result}");
            }

        }
        
    }
}
```

when input is 88 ,output is not correct

```
Please Provide input search No. :
88
88 is not found!
```

**Why is this happening?**
and
**I would also like to know how to print out the search process ?**

Thank you for the kindness help!

Comment: And where do you check that you've actually found the target and return its index? (Hint: Something like `if (Numbers[mid] == SearchItems) return mid;`.) Also I recommend you change the name of `SearchItems` to something like `target`.

Comment: Also (and this is VERY important) a binary search only works on a SORTED list!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
using System;

namespace BinarySearch
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int BinarySearch(int[] Numbers,int SearchItems)
        {
            int start = 0;
            int end = Numbers.Length - 1;
            while (start<=end)
            {
                int mid = (start + end) / 2;
                if (SearchItems == Numbers[mid])  //need this code to check equal value
                {  
                 return ++mid;  
                }  
                if (SearchItems<Numbers[mid])
                {
                    end = mid - 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    start = mid + 1;
                }
            }
            return -1;

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Provide input search No. :");
            int SearchItems = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] Numbers = { 8, 44, 26, 67, 35, 12, 77, 75, 31, 2, 62, 4, 88, 17 };
            Array.Sort(Numbers);
            int result = BinarySearch(Numbers, SearchItems);
            if (result<0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{SearchItems} is not found!");

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{SearchItems} is found at index:{result}");
            }

        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you incrementing `mid` before returning it?

Comment: Other wise it will not show the exact position of value.

Comment: What do you mean? You have `SearchItems == Numbers[mid]` therefore the value of `mid` is the index of the element in `Numbers` which matches `SearchItems`. After you increment `mid` then  `SearchItems == Numbers[mid]` will no longer be true (unless there are repeated values in the list, of course).

Comment: Index is started in array with 0 position so element 8 in the array is at [0] so if we return mid so result is shown as 8 is found at index 0 which is wrong that's why we use ++mid so our result will become as 8 is found at index 1.

Comment: Indices in C# are zero-based, not 1-based. For example, [`List<T>.BinarySearch()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=net-6.0) returns the zero-based index of an element that is found. It's perverse to return a 1-based index.